# Type must be known in this context when using Iterator::sum

Tags: types, rust, strong-typing

I am trying to implement a trait that models the euclidean distance between 2 points in an n-dim space. The points are represented as `Vec<u32>`.

```
pub trait Point {
    fn euclidean_to(&self, other: Vec<u32>) -> f64;
}

impl Point for Vec<u32> {
    fn euclidean_to(&self, other: Vec<u32>) -> f64 {
        (self.iter()
            .zip(other.iter())
            .map(|(xa, xb): (&u32, &u32)| (xa - xb).pow(2))
            .sum() as f64)
            .sqrt()
    }
}
```

Logic tells me that there is no reason for this not to work. As far as I know, the type parser works top to bottom, so all the types should be known. I am using Intellij-Rust and up until the `.map(|(xa, xb): (&u32, &u32)|` the compiler got the types just fine, at least I believe it did since it was able to figure out and give type hints about `(xa, xb)` before I explicitly specified the type.

As far as I can see, everything goes downhill when I use `sum()`. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something since it's pretty unlikely that the type parser wouldn't figure out that the sum of some `u32`s is another `u32` but it still gives the `type must be known in this context` treatment.

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: more minimal example: `fn main() { let ans = (0u32..10u32).sum(); }` fails to compile with `error[E0282]: type annotations needed`. If you turbo-fish the call to `sum` it will compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking the documentation for new functions. [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) is defined as:

```
fn sum<S>(self) -> S
where
    S: Sum<Self::Item>,
```

This means that it can be called on any iterator when the return type (`S`) can be created from the items of the iterator.

This conceptually allows an array of `i8`s to be summed to an `i8`, an `i16`, `i32`, etc. This flexibility comes at a price: you have to specify what type to sum to:

```
.sum::<MyType>()
```

You can also stash the result in an explicitly typed variable:

```
fn euclidean_to(&self, other: Vec<u32>) -> f64 {
    let x: u32 = self.iter()
        .zip(other)
        .map(|(xa, xb)| (xa - xb).pow(2))
        .sum();

    (x as f64).sqrt()
}
```

This is the exact same as [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thank you!